# Repeat image horizontally and vertically

Tags: ios, imageview

I want to repeat the following image:

[image]

to achieve the following background:

[image]

I tried a few codes as follow:

```
bluePatternView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_pattern.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0]];
```

and:

```
bluePatternView.backgroundColor = 
    [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_pattern.png"]];
```

I also tried to draw image with CGContextDrawTiledImage with no success.

**How that can be done?!**

**EDIT: result of implementing luk2302. please give him recognition by upvoting**

```
bluePatternView.backgroundColor = 
  [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_pattern.png"]];
```

result:

[image]

Comment: the first line did not work!? have you tried just using `bluePatternView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_pattern.png"]];`

Comment: `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth` is deprecated btw - if you want to use its functionality, use `resizableImageWithCapInsets` instead.

Comment: @luk2302 have you done this before? can you please help?

Comment: yes, I did. Should be very easy and straight forward!

Comment: it was the caching with the simulator and xcode. I had to delete the derived data from /Users/Apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Comment: oh no :( but yes, uninstalling and reinstalling an app should always be one of the first step if some very strange behaviour occurs...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As my comment already said: use

```
bluePatternView.backgroundColor = 
  [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_pattern.png"]];
```

You dont want to stretch your image. Let UIKit take care of the repetition.

Assuming that your bluePatternView is the actual large view for which you want to set a pattern as background. Maybe you are setting the background property of the wrong view if that code is still not working.

**Note:** duplicating the **SAME** image with @2x and @3x extension will lead to behaive properly for better resolution devices.

[image]

Comment: I tried this it repeats it horizontally and stretch it vertically

Comment: shall wee modify the view mode. Scale to fill or Aspect Fit. exists in interface builder

Comment: Now, they regard the content, not the background. Am i correct in assuming that you have a large view set up in IB and set the background via above code!?

Comment: yes, you are right. I updated the question with your code and result

Comment: Ok I wll check again!

Comment: Okay, that looks right. Maybe your background image has a too high resolution to be repeated more often. Or try to make your view bigger, especially taller

Comment: you have the images in the question. can you confirm that? it not a high resolution image I thought that in the beginning

Comment: you are right that code worked for other images! I will try to figure out what is the problem here!

Comment: Ok, I was expecting that it will take care of the screen size. 2x and 3x for iphone 6 plus. any idea how to do this?

Comment: Do that. The code is 100% correct - if it does not work, then something is wrong with your image or the actual view.

Comment: It does. If you provide `blue_pattern.png` and the appropriately named other images like `blue_pattern@2x.png` Xcode will choose the correct one!

Answer (score 31):

I found solution in **images.xcassets**,

**Step 1:-** Put your image to images.xcassets

**Step 2:-** Click on image, then click on bottom right corner written “Show Slicing”
[image: Put image]

**Step 3:-** Click on Start Slicing
[image: start slicing]

**Step 4:-** Click on "Slice Horizontally and Vertically" button
[image: Slice horizontally and vertically]

**Step 5:-** Here you will see 3-Horizontal and 3-Vertical slice lines.
[image]

- Put the most left vertical line to left side of image and both right most lines to right side of image.
- Put the most top line to top of image and both bottom most lines to bottom of image.
- So the final result will be looking like this.

[image]

**Step 6:-** Use this image.

And now image will be repeated.

[image]

**Note:- If you give slicing to 2x image it will repeat just 2x image, for 3x images you need to do the same slicing.**

[Example by Apple](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/deve65bd8d0d)

Comment: This works for me very well, even though my pattern image has very small design. Thanks.

Comment: what exactly does *slicing* mean in this context? or is it same as *repeating* something?

Comment: @Honey `Use the Xcode Slicing feature to specify the dimensions of a resizable center area of an image and to optionally specify end caps, which are areas of the image that should not be filled by the resizable area`
[See this.](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/deve65bd8d0d)

Comment: Any ideas why these images don't always work in launchscreen.storyboards but do always work in normal storyboards?

Comment: @ZaidPathan thank you so much for the amazing solution! I've been working on Xcode for about 3 years and never known about this!

Comment: Don't forgot that set image content mode to (Scale To Fill) in your imageView

Answer (score 5):

```
bluePatternView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "blue_pattern")!)
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save image in Assets then put those lines in `viewdidload`

```
bluePatternView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(patternImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "f8"))
```

This is for Swift 4.1.

Answer (score -1):

**this with Bellow Method using stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth like this way:-**

```
UIImage *backgroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"SheetBackground.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.5 topCapHeight:0];
```

as par your need example:-

```
UIImage *backgroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"q4Ses.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.5 topCapHeight:0];

  [_scro setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImage]];
```

Comment: I trired that. you copy it from another answer as it is?! I will try again!

Comment: i am also try this code its work for me thats why i give answer

Comment: this code stretches the image dont repeat it. stretch it vetically

Comment: I want a vertical and horizontal repeatition