# Xcode 8, Image Slicing Doesn't seems to be working

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

In my project, In Xcode 7 the image slicing was working fine.
After moving to Xcode 8 image slicing not working.

I followed everything given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30023188/3411787).

But final image looks like this:

[image: Actual final image]

Anything I'm missing for Xcode 8?

Comment: Show your original image, and show how you want it to end up looking.

Comment: Image and end result you can find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30001569/3411787)

Comment: Please explain, as there are several things going on in the page you linked. Do you want to **tile** an image? Or do you want to **stretch** an image? Or do you want to tile or stretch just **part** of an image?

Comment: I want to repeat full image given in question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30001569/3411787)

Comment: OK - so, in your code, you have this line? `bluePatternView.backgroundColor = 
  [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_pattern.png"]];`

Comment: No, I'm using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30023188/3411787) answer to repeat image.

Comment: That is only a partial answer. It's showing how to use slicing to make only a *portion* of the image the pattern for the background.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to repeat the whole image as image of UIImageView.

Comment: OK - please show the exact code you are using - not a link to someone else's partial code.

Comment: @DonMag, I'm sorry I think you didn't get my question.
I'm using image slicing provided by Xcode, no code required.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139593/discussion-between-donmag-and-zaid-pathan).

Comment: Curious... after mucking around with various images, I'm getting the impression that this is *not* by-design functionality, and only "just happened" to work previously. Very, very inconsistent results using a wide variety of images.

Answer (score 0):

Please check what you have as deployment target. Xcode image slicing supported for deployment targets iOS 7+

Comment: It's iOS 9+, the strange thing is it was working on older Xcode. :(

Comment: @ZaidPathan each storyboard/xib can override project setting for deployment target, check in the File Inspector in the Utilities area (on the right side). Please check it also