# Full screen background Image resolution for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I need a full screen background image for my iPhone app.
I have seen this [doc](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions)

It was helpful but my question is, we tens to have 1x, 2x, 3x resolutions for the image in iOS, but as per the document all the plus devices 6+,7+, 8+ renders 3x and iPhone X renders 3x but the resolutions is different for those devices,
so how can I pick a single image with 3 resolutions that fits all the device screens? from iPhone 5 - iPhone X ?

Comment: Look up "size classes"

Comment: if your image is repeating then try this easier way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30001569/repeat-image-horizontally-and-vertically

Comment: @user770 where can I look up "Size classes" ? can you elaborate more?

Comment: "Full Screen Background" is more of a design issue. If your "background" has various elements that don't look good when (slightly) scaled, then you may need to use a scalable background image, and make the elements separate image views that position themselves (via auto-layout) overlaid on top of the background.