# Repeat source image within SDAnimatedImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

I have a small tile image url (50x50) that I want to set for `SDAnimatedImageView` that occupies full screen. Is it possible to make my source tile image repeat within `SDAnimatedImageView` in vertical and horizontal axis so it occupies all space? Thus far closest I got to is using `contentMode` on `SDAnimatedImageView` to stretch this tile image, but that looks completely off.

Thus far I am not doing anything crazy, just `[self sd_setImageWithURL:url];` where self is `SDAnimatedImageView`

Comment: Possibility duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30001569/repeat-image-horizontally-and-vertically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself but I think you would have to use the image downloader and then set the image on the ImageView yourself with the tile option set.

```
- (nullable SDWebImageDownloadToken *)
    downloadImageWithURL:(nullable NSURL *)url
               completed:
                   (nullable SDWebImageDownloaderCompletedBlock)completedBlock;
```

[Docs](https://sdwebimage.github.io/Classes/SDWebImageDownloader.html#/c:objc(cs)SDWebImageDownloader(im)downloadImageWithURL:completed:)

```
- (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets 
                            resizingMode:(UIImageResizingMode)resizingMode;
```

[Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624127-resizableimagewithcapinsets?language=objc)

So I think it would work something like this:

```
[[SDWebImageManager sharedManager] downloadImageWithURL:imageURL
                                                options:SDWebImageRetryFailed
                                              completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
    self.imageView.image = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeTile];

}];
```